# How to write redshift aws query for matching string?

Tags: amazon-redshift

This is string pattern that i want to match . The string can be alpha or numeric or both (example of two different string)
"a252-449e8740ac24_1" ,
"9161-dbc9d0f07af9_0"

this is my query
`select * from table where string like '([0-9]|[a-z]%^-%[0-9]|[a-z]%^_[0-9])'`

This is not giving me output. i am new to aws redshift. please help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regex -

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE string ~ '^([0-9]|[a-z])*-([0-9]|[a-z])*_[0-9]$'
```

Redshift has the ~ operator which matches a string against a POSIX regex.

This page describes the regex patterns in detail (should you wish to make changes to the regex I specified) - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html